# Sum all the values in an array of factorials and print the result

Tags: java, arrays, math

I want to write a java program which will calculate the first 20 factorial and store them in an array. Then go through the array and sum all of the items and print the result on the screen.

Here is my code but I think I did something wrong:

```
public class ArrayQuestion4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long array[]= new long[20];
        long temp=1;

        for ( int i=1; i<20; i++){
            temp = i*(i+1);
            temp = temp*(temp+1);
            array[i]=temp;
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }

        for ( int i=1; i<20; i++){
            temp = array[i];
            temp = array[i]+(array[i+1]);
            temp = temp+(temp+1);
            System.out.println(temp);
        }       
    }
}
```

The answer that comes out is not correct by the way.

I figure it out the correct code is this:

```
public class ArrayQuestion4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long array[]= new long[20];
    array[0]=1;
    long temp=0;
    for ( int i=1; i<20; i++){
        array[i]=array[i-1]*(i+1);
        System.out.println(array[i-1]+"*"+(i+1)+" = "+array[i]);
    }   

    for ( int i=1; i<20; i++){
       temp = temp + array[i-1] + array[i];
    }   
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Sum = "+temp);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The first recursion is not the one of the factorial, the second on is not the one for a sum. Hint: You do not need any `temp` variables. But you need a `sum` variable.

Comment: The number that comes out is not correct

Comment: Come on people just explain what I did wrong, I can only ask a question every 90 mins.

Comment: @jackzhang though I can sympathize with the difficulty in learning algorithms, I think LutzL was encouraging you to look for the answer on your own after considering a hint as doing so is a much more effective way to learn. You will only get down votes with responses like that.

Comment: "I can only ask a question every 90 minutes."  I would suggest you work through a tutorial to learn more about java.  In addition to limiting how often you can ask a question, SO isn't design to get the best answers immediately.

Comment: At least I am showing you guys the code I did to prove to you guys that I did try to solve this question, but as you can see before I updated my question that I don't know how to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

As an illustration of where the code is probably not doing what you want it to be doing, look at what you get for **(2)!**

```
temp = i*(i+1);       //temp = 1*(1+1); which is 2
temp = temp*(temp+1); //temp = 2*(2+1); which is 6
array[i] = temp;      //array[1] = 6; - also note we skip ever assigning array[0]
```

You get 6 as an answer, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The way you define factorial of n is
fact(n) = n * fact(n-1)

In the solution, factorial[n] represents factorial(n).
and temp is the current factorial being calculated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long factorial[] = new long[20];
    //Because Fact(1) = 1 * Fact(0), and fact(0) = 1.
    factorial[0] = 1;

    for (int n = 1; n < 20; n++) {
        // Loop needs to be <20 because i have defined the array size = 20.            
        // <= would get an array out of bound exception. You can change the limits as you want.

        //calculating  the factorial based on formula:
        // Factorial(N) = n * Facorial(N-1);
        long factorialOfN = n*factorial[n-1];

        //storing back the value in the array for future use.
        factorial[n] = factorialOfN;

       //Printing it.
        System.out.println(factorialOfN);
    }
}
```

Comment: and this would probably not work like K139 said. so use BigInt with the current logic, if that happens

Comment: I just verified that after posting this. I'll let the comment be there in-case someone decides to use a larger number.

Comment: It might also be helpful to annotate with an explanation of initializing the 0-th element outside the loop and the < 20 comparison in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`Long` could not hold sum of all 20! results. There is a limit for 'long' in Java and it is

```
 public static final long MAX_VALUE = 0x7fffffffffffffffL;

 which is 9223372036854775807
```

Use 'BigInteger' to get correct answer. And also refer '[How (not) to write Factorial in Java](http://chaosinmotion.com/blog/?p=622)'

Comment: 20! = 2,432,902,008,176,640,000 which is less than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Comment: As @DoubleDouble said, long will hold the value in this case, though max value does indeed become a concern very quickly.